# Are bootstrapped parameter standard errors unbiased in time series data?

Tags: time-series, bootstrap

I'm analyzing multivariate panel data which includes autocorrelated time series variables. The response variable is binary and I'm considering a random intercept to account for between subject variation. So a mixed effect logistic regression seems to be in order.

Is it safe to say if I ignore the autocorrelation structure that my parameter estimates will still be unbiased, but their standard errors will be biased too low?

To remedy this, can I use block bootstrapping to estimate unbiased standard errors for my model parameters?